# Default values for variables not set when creating new HTTPRequest?

Tags: apex, httprequest, http

If you create a new HTTPRequest and don't specify a header, what does it default to when you send it using Http.send()?

Comment: There is no Object named HttpHeader so not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I apologize, I meant HTTPRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested your question with the following code

```
public class RestGet {
    public static void testGet(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('http://requestb.in/ux2a10ux');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

http://requestb.in/ is a free service, that allows you to debug sent to your temporary endpoint callout.

In my case:

```
HEADERS

Cf-Connecting-Ip: 85.222.138.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Total-Route-Time: 0
Host: requestb.in
Pragma: no-cache
Cf-Ipcountry: GB
Connect-Time: 1
X-Request-Id: 20873277-7c62-4b24-810b-dd9595947a68
Sfdc-Stack-Depth: 1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Cf-Ray: .....
Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}
Via: 1.1 vegur
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/39.0
```

So you can see all default populated headers.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing but if you debug those headers on the `HttpRequest` itself, they're all null. So...I guess maybe the `Http` class adds them in.